# Changing the UISearchBar returnKeyType to Done works on an iPhone 5 but crashes the app on an iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, viewdidload

I have a bizarre problem.

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` embedded at the top. I have changed the "`returnKeyType`" to say Done instead of Search using the following code in the `viewDidLoad` of my `UITableViewController`:

```
[(UITextField *)self.timelineSearchBar setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyDone];
[(UITextField *)self.timelineSearchBar setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
```

That code works perfectly for my iPhone 5s. However, if I plug my iPhone 4s (running iOS 7 also), it crashes on those two lines. I put in an exception breakpoint and it lead me to that and true enough, if I comment those two out, it works on the 4s again.

With being relatively new to development, how can I go about understanding/fixing what's causing the issues here?

My 4s Storyboard is made to be identical to the 5 storyboard and this TableView and SearchBar is all created in Storyboard. I have checked and both are hooked up to the same property (timelineSearchBar).

Any thoughts would be really great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `timelineSearchBar` is indeed a property of type `UISearchBar` then these calls should actually fail on *both* devices. `UISearchBar` does not inherit from `UITextField`, and so does not implement the two methods you are trying to call. Your cast to `UITextField` is unsafe and is probably the source of your errors.

If you really want to change these properties of your search bar, you can look through the subviews until your find the actual `UITextField`, and set your properties on that. The following method will find the text field from the subviews:

```
-(UITextField*)findTextFieldInSubviewsRecursively:(UIView*)view
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        return (UITextField*)view;
    }

    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews){
        UITextField* field = [self findTextFieldInSubviewsRecursively:subView];
        if(field != nil){
            return field;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then you just need to set your values:

```
UITextField* searchBarTextField = [self findTextFieldInSubviewsRecursively:self.timelineSearchBar];
// Set your stuff on the text field
```

But this approach is probably not recommended and may not even work

Comment: I've tested this approach and it works on iOS 6 and iOS 7, but not 7.1

Comment: Many thanks @michaels - I've just tested it on 7.1 and it worked for my 4s and continues to work for my 5. The reason for wanting this approach is actually so that I can have the user to dismiss the keyboard without typing anything in from the UISearchBar with the "Done" button and the second line. This is also enforced by the fact that I removed the "Cancel" button next to the UISearchBar, so only the x appears when you start typing ,but there's no intuitive way to dismiss the keyboard if you haven't typed anything in. I've implemented the dismiss on scroll but I feel my less intuitive

Comment: users may not know that. The question is... is this dangerous enough a call to get the app rejected? The app is in the app store and this is the second update. Alternatively, without this approach, is there a similar way to achieve what I'm trying to (dismiss the keyboard with blank text without a cancel button next to the UISeachBar? really appreciate your assistance with this

Comment: I have this code live in a number of apps and it hasn't been grounds for rejection - though I can't guarantee anything, of course, since I don't work for Apple.

Instead of the scroll, you could add a UITapGestureRecognizer that dismisses the keyboard if the user taps away (i.e. anywhere else than the search bar or keyboard) - that's a bit more intuitive than having to scroll.

Comment: Ahh ,that does make sense indeed actually. I will certainly try that out and for now, your code here has been a massive help. Won't hold anything against you :) but thanks again - really appreciate it!